# Inheritance and private variables in Java

Tags: java, android, inheritance, private, chronometer

I'm trying to add a method to the Chronometer class in android. It stores the start time in this variable:

```
private long mBase;
```

so I thought I could do this

```
public class MyChronometer extends Chronometer{

    public void reset(){
        long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        this.mBase = now;
    }
}
```

but Android Studio is telling me that `mBase` can't be found. Why is this? And what am I doing wrong? From what I understand of inheritance in Java, if I extend a class then I have all of the methods and variables of the class I extend which I can then add to. Is this incorrect? Wouldn't this include the `mBase` variable even though it is private?

Edit: Essentially I am trying to create a setter function for `mBase`

Comment: I think it's only its protected and public members, not private.

Comment: *" if I extend a class then I have all of the methods and variables of the class I extend"* The instance has them, but your derived class code can't access the private ones, just the public and protected ones. (BTW, they're "fields," not "variables.")

Comment: There would be no point in `private` if you could do this!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm quoting the [tutorial - Private Members in a Superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> A subclass does not inherit the `private` members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has `public` or `protected` methods for accessing its `private` fields, these can also be used by the subclass.

Meaning that you cannot *directly* access the `private` fields, but you can use methods that give you access to them. This [table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) might be helpful as well:

```
                  Access Levels
------------+---------+---------+-----------+------
Modifier    |   Class | Package |  Subclass | World
------------+---------+---------+-----------+------
public      |     Y   |    Y    |     Y     |   Y
protected   |     Y   |    Y    |     Y     |   N
no modifier |     Y   |    Y    |     N     |   N
private     |     Y   |    N    |     N     |   N
```

Comment: What should I do then to add a setter for the private variable? Create a new variable to use? I guess I could just copy and paste and add what I want from the original class but that just feels kind of wrong.

Comment: No. You create a protected or public method that simply returns that field.

Comment: thats what I was trying but I got an error, which is what led me to ask this question. If I refer to this variable at all, like if I make a public setter, it will not compile because it doesn't know what `mBuilder` is.

Comment: If it's private then there is a reason why it is, and probably the author don't want to give you access to it. You can use reflection or ask the author to change the modifier :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getters` to access the private fields of a parent class.

These methods are *usually* used only to return the private value.

Code example of `setter` and `getter`:

Reference link: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

```
public class Printer {

    @Inject @Informal Greeting greeting;

    private String name;
    private String salutation;

    public void createSalutation() {
        this.salutation = greeting.greet(name);
    }

    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this, what I am trying to do is add a setter method. How would I do that if the original class did not come with one?